# Does a label tag, and the element it is related to, have to be children elements within a form?

Tags: html, forms, label

From [the documentation of a `label` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label):

> ### Attributes
>
> (...)
>
> **`for`**. The `id` of a labelable form-related element in the same document as the `<label>` element.

Must this be the `id` of an element nested under a `form`?

I have a `select` element that is not associated with any `form`. The value of this `select` does not have to be sent to the server and even when it will, it seems cumbersome for me to do this by submitting a `form`. Is this incorrect? Yet I would like to describe what this `select` does, so I want a `label`, but there is no `form`, so am I allowed to place a `label`?

Or do I need a `form` element, even if its only purpose will be to wrap a single `select` inside a single `label`?

<sub>Longer story, if you wish to know: Web game, players can build teams and enter battles with these teams. Ultimately I want something more sophisticated, but for the sake of prototyping I now have a `select` element whose `option`s are simply teams' names. So when the player chooses a team, it is simply set as the currently active team. Now they can enter the teambuilder to view it or queue in the matchmaker. If they modify the team and save it, then it will be sent to the server; and if they queue to battle the team will also be sent to server; but in both cases additional data sent alongside the team's ID will differ significantly, so I don't see how can I make this `select` a part of a `form` that may be later submitted to the server.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

That description does not imply that a `label` must be associated with a form-related element that is a descendant of a `form` via its `for` attribute. It's saying that it must be associated with an element that is *typically* used in forms. Most, though not all, of these elements are also known as form *controls*. Neither the `label` nor its associated control is required to be a descendant of a `form`, let alone one that is to be submitted.